# Select row by ID of another row in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Supose I have a table like that:

```
+------+------+
|  ID  |ID_REF|
+------+------+
|1     |null  |
+------+------+
|2     |3     |
+------+------+
|3     |null  |
+------+------+
```

How can I `select` a row by its `ID` and also its referenced row in column `ID_REF` ?

For example:

- if I select row with id 2 in this table I would have to get the row with id 3 also;
- if I select row with id 1, I will only get it.

---

**EDIT**

I am using **MySQL** dbms.

Comment: Show us the effort and tag the dbms

Comment: @BibinMatthew, did that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS`

```
select *
from your_table t1
where id = 2 or exists (
   select *
   from your_table t2
   where t1.id = t2.id_ref and t2.id = 2
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for and I really didn't understand why I get downvoted.

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara: your question probably got dowvoted because of http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see now, I will edit my post.